# Seeking birth record for Adam Hausam at Kirchheim-Bolanden, Germany?

Tags: germany, birth-records, rhineland-palatinate

I am interested in knowing if my 3rd Great Grandfather, named Adam Hausam, supposedly a tailor,  was born in Kirchheim-Bolanden, Germany. Where can I find his birth-record?

It was rumored he was from Denmark.

Andreas Hausam, son of Adam Hausam and Elizabeth Suder, was born in Kirchheim in 1832 and migrated to the U.S around 1866 where he married a woman whose last name was Tisch and supposedly from the same area of Germany.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  What is the source of the information you posted in your question? Posting how you know what you know lets us see what you have already looked at, and makes it easier for us to suggest other things you could research. You can use the edit link under your question to edit it and add information.

Answer (score 2):

If your ancestor was a lutheran, the relevant church records of Kirchheimbolanden are available via [Archion](http://www.archion.de):

[Zentralarchiv der evangelischen Kirche der Pfalz → Kirchheimbolanden](https://www.archion.de/de/browse/?path=51336-413093&cHash=7da5337cff6f1e55fe32a6a7e97b9fd6#https://www.archion.de/de/browse/&path=51336-413093-413219)

As of today, the site is only available in German and there are no indexed records as you might know it from Ancestry/FamilySearch/… Most records however contain a contemporary index where you can search according to the surname. Knowledge of [Kurrent handwriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) is needed.